# How to copy only the first sheets of workbooks in a folder into one excel workbook

Tags: excel, vba

So I'm using this code, and it is fantastic. If I can get some clues how to tweak it so it only copies the first sheet of the workbooks its pulling from. SIDE NOTE - Please keep in mind that not every workbook's first sheet is titled "Sheet1", some have names inputted.

```
Sub MergeMultipleWorkbooks()

'Define Variables
Dim Path, FileName As String

'Assign Values to Variables
Path = Assign a Folder  which contains excel files for example "C:\Merge\"
FileName = Dir(Path & "*.xlsx")

'Check FileName in the Given Location
Do While FileName <> ""

'Open Excel File
Workbooks.Open FileName:=Path & FileName, ReadOnly:=True

'Copy all the sheet to this workbook
For Each Sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
Sheet.Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
Next Sheet

'Close the ActiveWorkbook
Workbooks(FileName).Close
'Assign a Excel FileName

'Assign Next Excel FileName
FileName = Dir()
Loop

'Display a Message
MsgBox "Files has been copied Successfull", , "MergeMultipleExcelFiles"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Sub MergeMultipleWorkbooks()


    Dim Path, FileName As String

    Path = "C:\Merge\" 
    FileName = Dir(Path & "*.xlsx")

    Do While FileName <> ""

        With Workbooks.Open(FileName:=Path & FileName, ReadOnly:=True)
            .Worksheets(1).Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1) 
            .Close False
        End With

        FileName = Dir() 
    Loop

    MsgBox "Files has been copied Successfull", , "MergeMultipleExcelFiles" 
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You have all the parts and pieces here. I just got rid of the For Each loop.

```
Sub MergeMultipleWorkbooks()
    'Define Variables
     Dim Path, FileName As String
    'Assign Values to Variables
     Path = "C:\Merge\"
     FileName = Dir(Path & "*.xlsx")
    'Check FileName in the Given Location
    Do While FileName <> ""
        'Open Excel File
        Workbooks.Open FileName:=Path & FileName, ReadOnly:=True
        'Copy the first sheet in file into this workbook
        Sheets(1).Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
        'Close the ActiveWorkbook
         Workbooks(FileName).Close
        'Assign Next Excel FileName
        FileName = Dir()
    Loop
    'Display a Message
    MsgBox "Files has been copied Successfully", , "MergeMultipleExcelFiles"
End Sub
```

Comment: oh wow. im going to try this at the library tomorrow. thank you and happy holidays